# Can I read a column value from out sys_refcursor with in the same Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I have a stored procedure that selects some of the column values from multiple tables(inner join) and returns a sys_refcursor. Now i got a new requirement where I need to get one of the column values in the select list within the same stored procedure and update one of the tables participated in above inner join. Is there any way I can read the refcursor within the same stored proc and get the value? Or can you suggest any other better ways?

Comment: You can do that before opening the ref cursor

Comment: This is a poor requirement. Good practice is to keep update activity separate from reporting activity (Principle of Least Astonishment). Also, a Ref Cursor is a pointer not a result set in its own right: we can only read it once. So we can't change the data in the cursor because there's no data there. You need to apply the update to the target table first,, then issue the SELECT which gets the Ref Cursor. Just write a new procedure to do it, which can call the existing procedure for the Ref Cursor part - duplication of code is unnecessary.